# Select and sum values by weeks/months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash of dates and amounts like so:

```
{
  "2014-01-30"=>200.1, 
  "2014-02-01"=>27.86, 
  "2014-02-02"=>55.72, 

  "2014-02-03"=>83.58, 
  "2014-02-04"=>83.58, 
  "2014-02-05"=>76.41, 
  "2014-02-06"=>187.85, 
  "2014-02-07"=>27.86, 
  "2014-02-08"=>27.86, 
  "2014-02-09"=>55.72, 

  "2014-02-10"=>269.34, 
  "2014-02-11"=>83.58, 
  "2014-02-12"=>159.99, 
  "2014-02-13"=>373.61, 
  "2014-02-14"=>264.26, 
  "2014-02-15"=>236.4, 

  "2014-02-17"=>215.71, 
  "2014-02-18"=>55.72, 
  "2014-02-19"=>132.13, 
  "2014-02-20"=>104.27, 
  "2014-02-21"=>83.58, 
  "2014-02-22"=>104.27, 
  "2014-02-23"=>159.99, 

  "2014-02-24"=>27.86, 
  "2014-02-25"=>172.24, 
  "2014-02-27"=>380.78, 
  "2014-02-28"=>336.82, 
  "2014-03-01"=>55.72, 
  "2014-03-02"=>83.58, 

  "2014-03-03"=>83.58, 
  "2014-03-04"=>224.02, 
  "2014-03-05"=>574.76, 
  "2014-03-06"=>853.14, 
  "2014-03-07"=>27.86, 
  "2014-03-09"=>83.58, 

  "2014-03-10"=>241.48, 
  "2014-03-11"=>208.54, 
  "2014-03-12"=>368.53, 
  "2014-03-13"=>941.42, 
  "2014-03-14"=>396.39, 
  "2014-03-15"=>320.71, 
  "2014-03-16"=>144.38, 

  "2014-03-17"=>215.71, 
  "2014-03-18"=>83.58, 
  "2014-03-19"=>227.44, 
  "2014-03-20"=>104.27, 
  "2014-03-21"=>111.32, 
  "2014-03-22"=>104.27, 
  "2014-03-23"=>238.86, 

  "2014-03-25"=>172.24
}
```

What I want to do is map those dates into "week" and "month" groups and sum the amount.

So basically take the starting date and the ending date (in this case, `2014-01-30` and `2014-03-25`) and then divide it in to calendar week periods and month periods and sum all the amounts of days in that range.

In my example data above, you'll see it divided into actual weeks. And notice, a couple of those groupings only have 6 items as there wasn't an amount on one of the days.

For the output, I'd want an array of each week/month range sum'd amount.

Output of the example data above would be: `[283.68, 542.86, 1387.18, 855.67, 1057.00, 1846.94, 2621.45, 1085.45, 172.24]`

FWIW, I'm suing Ruby 2 and Rails 4.

Comment: The hash keys are actual `Date` objects or strings? Can you please post an example of the output you want to get?

Comment: @toro2k: Yes, they are actual `Date` objects. Output would just be an  array of each week/month range sum'd amount.

Comment: Please provide a valid input and a valid expected output. Help us help you :P

Comment: Have you written code, or are you asking us to write it for you? If you've written code please show us the pertinent part. And, as is, your hash is invalid. Please provide a corrected version.

Answer (score 3):

```
# This for using outside Rails, remove if on Rails
require 'date'
gem 'activesupport'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date'
require 'active_support/core_ext/enumerable'

hash = {
  "2014-01-30"=>200.1, 
  "2014-02-01"=>27.86, 
  "2014-02-02"=>55.72, 

  [...]

  "2014-03-25"=>172.24
}

# group by week
p Hash[ hash.map { |h, v| [Date.parse(h), v] } ]
    .group_by { |h, v| h.cweek }
    .values
    .map { |v| v.sum { |v| v.last } }
    .map { |v| v.round(2) }

#=> [283.68, 542.86, 1387.18, 855.67, 1057.0, 1846.94, 2621.45, 1085.45, 172.24]

# group by month
p Hash[ hash.map { |h, v| [Date.parse(h), v] } ]
    .group_by { |h, v| h.month }
    .values
    .map { |v| v.sum { |v| v.last } }
    .map { |v| v.round(2) }

#=> [200.1, 3786.99, 5865.38]
```

After some refactoring:

```
# group by week
p hash
    .group_by { |h, _| Date.parse(h).cweek }
    .map { |_, v| v.sum { |v| v.last }.round(2) }

# group by month
p hash
    .group_by { |h, _| Date.parse(h).month }
    .map { |_, v| v.sum { |v| v.last }.round(2) }
```

If you are curious about why I used the underscore: http://po-ru.com/diary/rubys-magic-underscore/

Comment: Fantastic! What about on a month-to-month basis? So instead of grouping by calendar weeks, group by calendar months.

Comment: Just replace `cweek` with `cmonth`

Comment: I'm not seeing that `cmonth` is an actual method.

Comment: Don't require all of Active Support just for a method. Read how to use [the Active Support core extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) and cherry-pick just what is needed.

Comment: @Shpigford `month`, I'm sorry; answer updated. @theTinMan, it is a proof of concept, it isn't useful for the answer taking care about details like that. Usually I leave refactoring up to the user too, like f.e. the first `map` can be avoid changing the `group_by` block to `{ |h, v| Date.parse(h).cweek }`, but as I said I prefer not to waste time in improvements that are not related with the answer

Comment: @theTinMan since you made me think about refactoring, I updated the answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
start_date = hash.min[0]
end_date = hash.max[0]
result = []
(start_date..end_date).each do |date|
  if date.wday == start_date.wday
    result << hash[date]
  else
    result[-1] += hash[date]
  end
end
```

Or just for the fun :

```
(h.min[0]..h.max[0]).each {|d| (d.wday == h.min[0].wday && r << h[d])||(r[-1]+=h[d])}
```

Comment: `hash.first[0]`? Don't count on hash value order. Hashes retain their insertion order in Ruby, but the assumption the order of elements is also ordered by date is not safe. At a minimum code that needs the first and last elements should use a [`minmax`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax) and find the values by their Date, DateTime or Time equivalents.